# fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin' in xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode5, darwin

Project getting build in `xcode 5.0.1` but not in `xcode5.1.1`. I have tried to remove `arm64` from valid architecture and build architecture but I am getting same error.

I have referred lots of post on stackoverflow but no one help on this issue.

Can anyone help me on this?

EDIT: Here is the screenshot of error message.

[image: Here is the screenshot of error message.]

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: Please see attached screenshot in EDIT.

Comment: I'd like to see the actual error message on the files that failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Librairies -> add (+) Foundation.framework.

Your project-Prefix.pch should look like:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Or, if you have *Enable Modules* in Build Settings:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    @import UIKit;
    @import Foundation;
#endif
```

Else, have you tried to re-install Xcode?